# How do I prove this g set-equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∩ B)' = (A ∩ B') ∪ (A'∩ B)

(A ∪ B) ∩ (A' ∪ B') = (A ∩ B') ∪ (A'∩ B)  =  De Morgans Law

I do not know from here how to tackle this problem. I can't take out A from both since one is a complement.

I have been stuck here for the past two days. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apply double distributivity:
$$(A\cup B)\cap(A\cap B)'=(A\cup B)\cap(A'\cup B')=(\underset{\strut=\,\varnothing}{A\cap A'})\cup(A\cap B')\cup(B\cap A')\cup(\underset{\strut=\,\varnothing}{B\cap B'}). $$